# How can I make this text and image not overlap

Tags: html, css, web

I know this looks very simple, but I have been trying to figure out a solution for an hour now. I have an "a" element with text and an image inside. The problem is that the image goes below the text, and I want them lined up.

```css
a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        color: #ff5c33;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #nav-user-logo{
        max-height: 16px;
    }
```

```html
     <!-- Header right part --> 
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a>
                        User123
                        <img src="Images/Icons/user.svg" id="nav-user-logo" alt='User123'>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content user-dropdown-content" >
                        <a>AW Admin</a>
                        <a>Account Settings</a>
                        <a>Change Password</a>
                        <a>Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was something super simple. This code is in a header, on the right side, and the "a" element was too small to display the code and image side by side. I fixed it with the following:

```
<!-- Header right part --> 
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a style="display:inline-block; width: 150px;">
                    User123
                    <img src="Images/Icons/user.svg" id="nav-user-logo" alt='User123'>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content user-dropdown-content" >
                    <a>AW Admin</a>
                    <a>Account Settings</a>
                    <a>Change Password</a>
                    <a>Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the issue myself but you can do

```
#nav-user-logo {
  max-height: 1em;
  display: inline;
}
```

to guarantee it is inline with the text.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that did not work, turns out it was something much simpler. I posted a comment with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By defect, any browser, with your `css` will display the image side by side as, I think, you want:

example with your code:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
   
}

a:hover {
    color: #ff5c33;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-user-logo{
    max-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
   <a>
     User123
     <img src="https://www.ajvs.com/redirect/5/Agilent_IMG300_UHV_R0343301_1,8926cf9ec9ce009a52f3ea8866b07f5f" id="nav-user-logo" alt='User123'>
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-content user-dropdown-content">
     <a>AW Admin</a>
     <a>Account Settings</a>
     <a>Change Password</a>
     <a>Logout</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Probably, you have some kind of "reset" `css sheet` that is turning all your images as `display:block` It's quite common in many wordpress themes. You may need to overwrite these css adding `img {display:inline-block}` or similar rule. Calling to the id image or class to not break your whole theme.

Comment: I am not working with wordpress. I am making my website from scratch to learn some HTML and CSS. Turns out the problem I was having was something very simple, I have posted a comment with the answer. Thank you